# Multisite - Images often getting uploaded to the wrong month directory

Tags: multisite, uploads, media, media-library

Previously I had only a single site enabled but recently enabled a multisite option. Now the issue is that the images are getting uploaded in the wrong month directory. It should be uploading to 11 but the images on the main site are being uploaded to 7 and images for the second site are being uploaded to 10. Time is correctly showing in the server configuration and WordPress. I did come across a thread where they have suggested to disable ms_files_rewriting but I could not find the option mentioned. I have included the screenshot of the uploaded for both the sites below. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Main Site**
[image: Main Site]

**Second Site**
[image: Second Site]